# Ionic 4 Console.Log() not showing in function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, logging

What on Earth is happening here. No console output inside this service function of mine. Any one had this issue before?

```
   test(){
    console.log('TESTING???')
    console.log('TESTING???')
    return 'HALOOOOOOO??'
  }
```

Calling the function

```
console.log('Before Test')
console.log(this.emergencyService.test())
console.log('After Test')
```

Output

[image]

Some more info.

- Calling that function from a normal Page
- Function is inside a Service I inject into that page

Comment: Can you make this same in jsfiddle?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I think this has something to do with the service I am injecting, dont know if fiddle has that functionality (to inject services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a filter on my console.

Clearing it solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the value of the method. If instead of `console.log(this.emergencyService.test())` you add `this.emergencyService.test()`, what does it show? It returns the two `console.log()`, no?